# Set origin to 3d cursor without rotating it

Tags: edit-mode, transforms, 3d-cursor, origin

The origin of this mesh is at the center. I'd like to move it to the top surface. First I move the 3D cursor there:

[image]

Then I set origin to 3D cursor:

[image]

The problem is, not only the location, but the rotation of origin is set as 3D cursor's. How can I set origin to 3D cursor's location only?

Comment: I don’t know. On my blender, the default is to not use the 3-D cursor’s orientation. You probably turned this on somewhere. Check operator panel.

Comment: Can you switch on the object's 'Axis' in Properties > Viewport Display?  I can't reproduce this. Is your Transform Orientation set to 3D Cursor? The gizmo will be oriented with Object axes only if the Transform Orientation is set to 'Local'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty weird, In my case it does only move the cursor, and I've tried with different Transformation orientations, and transformation pivot point settings, always with the same result.
By any chance, maybe you have gizmo setting "Object Gizmos" - in gizmo dropdown menu - set up to 3d cursor?
In object mode: Object->Set Origin->Origin to 3d cursor.

Worst case worse, more a workaround rather than convenient tool, before you set origin to 3d cursor you can change cursor orientation to match your object's by typing the command in the console:

```
bpy.context.scene.cursor.rotation_euler = bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active.rotation_euler
```

probably it should be comment rather than answer, but it was too long!

Comment: Ok, now I get it... I used MACHIN3TOOLS's `Origin to 3D cursor` instead of Blender's built-in one. I didn't realize because they have the same name. I'm not sure if I should close this question.

Comment: @Lai Please post your comment as a full answer :). Then it will help others with the same problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

For future reference:

[image]

I used "Set Mesh Object's Origin to Cursor", without realizing the operator is provided by an addon called [MACHIN3tools](https://blendermarket.com/products/MACHIN3tools), instead of Blender itself. It copies both location and rotation by default, and one can copy location only by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>.